# Where to put xsl file in java project?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I use Jdeveloper and weblogic and right now I put the xsl file inside the java project.  The problem is whenever I need to modify the xsl file, I have to re-deploy the java project again.  I have 2 questions

1) Is there a place that I can put the xsl file so I don't need to re-deploy the java project whenever I need to modify the xsl?  Maybe in the domain directory?

2) Is there a directory where you recommend to put the xsl file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In one project I participated we saved stylesheet in the database and read from it. It was pretty good for simpler one-file stylesheets and easy to make updates. Of course, in more complicated scenarios (like if you import/include one stylesheet into other, etc.) it might be counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you provide the absolute file of path
e.g. C:/file.xls

If the file is inside your project and mapped by a relative path, then you would need to redeploy every time you change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to put the file in the domain's directory structure, it's best to put it somewhere under /WEB-INF/. Otherwise, the file can be served *directly* to the client by the server, like an ordinary web page, which you likely don't want.